# Precautions while redesigning site appearing in google search first page

Tags: seo, google-search, ranking, google-ranking, redesign

One of our clients site need to be re-designed. The updates would be mostly presentational including graphics, page layout updates (re-order page elements), color, icons, fonts, making it responsive etc. There will be minor content updates, mostly correcting old data and add some new.

Currently site pages appear on Google search first page for key business phrases/words.

What precautions should be taken while re-designing website without affecting the search ranking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clear cut instructions but this what we do for our clients who is already ranking.

1. We will use same SEO plugin (no changes means rules also will stay same).
2. Does not modify meta & schema.
3. Will try not change title tags & image file names wih alt tags.
4. Finally keep an eye on keyword density for our targeted keywords.
5. Keep an eye on other onpage SEO factors.

There is a higher possibility of rank fluctuation even for small change so except to move around in search engine results but once it's settle it will be back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The checklist makes sense. Thanks again